# What is the opposite of 'git checkout HEAD^'?

Tags: git, git-checkout

I'm walking through git history with command `git checkout`. From `master` I went to e.g commit with hash `a7040f35a1e`.

```
git checkout a7040f35a1e
```

Then I went to the previous commit:

```
git checkout HEAD^
```

How can I return back? I mean how can I go to following commit? Is it possible with the word `HEAD` + or something?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't any specific way to get to the following commit, but there are a few things you can use:

- Use `git checkout -`. This is shorthand for `git checkout @{-1}` which means “checkout the last thing I checked out”. This solves the specific case of getting back to where you just were, but not the general case of getting to the next commit from where you are.
- Use the name of the commit, tag, or branch, e.g. after `git checkout master^` you could use `git checkout master`.

This is probably true because of the way Git stores relationships between commits: each commit knows the ID of its parent commit(s), so it's easy to follow that relationship from `x` to `x^`, but the commits don't know the IDs of their children, so there's no efficient way to do the reverse lookup.

There's a lot of information about ways of referring to commits in the Git documentation. Checkout `git help revisions`.

Answer (score 8):

Git doesn't have an operator for "the following commit", as a single commit may have multiple "children". If you want to return to the previous commit, do so explicitly - `git checkout a7040f35a1e`.

Comment: A single commit can also have multiple parents (e.g. a merge commit), and there is a way to get to those using `^`. I think it's more to do with children storing the IDs of their parent, but parents not knowing the IDs of their children.

Answer (score 1):

Git keeps a history of the last checked out `HEAD`s.

You can use `git checkout HEAD@{1}` to the previous one.

See `git reflog` for the full history.

Answer (score 0):

You can return back by using the same command you used to get there initially:

```
$ git checkout a7040f35a1e
```

Comment: Of course I know :) this wasn't actually my question. I'm curious about walking one step up and one step down

Comment: @areim I've been StackOverflowing all day. People who know are mostly indistinguishable from those who don't. More seriously, default up is `~`, specific ups are `^`, there is no down, though there is a back through the reflog with `@`.